Missing Auth Token - LinkedIn OIDC Signin
Getting a 'Missing Auth token error' when using my LinkedIn app to sign in with OIDC.
Seems like a bug.
LinkedIn is the IDP (Identity Provider) in my OAuth flow.

Error from identity provider: unauthorized_scope_error Scope "r_emailaddress" is not authorized for your application

enter image description hereenter image description here
I have generated an OAuth token on my app. With the correct scopes.
OAuth scopes on my app are openid, profile and email so I would have assumed the app is authorised.
Please help
